# Images as Plane with Principled Shader should be less influenced by the environment. Combine with Emission Node?

Tags: materials, light, image, lighting, color-management

I have a person who was filmed behind a green screen and cut out. Now I have inserted them into my scene using "Images as Plane", but I have a problem: I want to be able to determine how strongly the person is influenced by the environment. If I set "Principled" under Material Settings when importing, it is 100% influenced by the environment in terms of brightness, etc. Often, however, the picture appears too dark compared to the environment and the colors are sometimes changed too much. I tried to work around the problem with an emission node to make the video brighter, but I just couldn't get it to work. Does any of you have experience with it or how do you do it? Thanks!

Here with the normal principled shader. The person is influenced by the light, but a bit too dark.
[image]
Here with an emission node. I can control, how bright the person is, but it isn´t transparent and it is also no longer influenced by the environment. So I want it to be influenced by the surroundings, but still want to be able to increase the brightness of the person a little if necessary.
[image]

Comment: It's a bit hard to see what you mean with just words may be can you add some screenshoots or a blend file? (or both..)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I now added 2 pictures!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the *Mix Shader Node* like this:

**100% afected by the enviroment:**
[image]

**50% afected by the enviroment:**
[image]

**0% afected by the enviroment:**
[image]

The second *Mix Shader Node* setup is for a *Image Texture* with transparency to work.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what i was searching for. Thank you very much 

Comment: Happy this help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to mix a transparent shader with the emission shader, using the alpha channel of the image to select.  Something like this:

[image: mixing transparency and emission using alpha]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But with Ayo Reis solution it is also influenced by the environment.